# mechanics piston problem involving rotational motion.

Tags: trigonometry, physics, classical-mechanics

[image]

The above figure shows a piston driving a crank OP pivoted at the end $O$.
The piston slides in a straight cylinder and the crank is made to rotate with constant angular velocity $ \omega $. Find the distance $OQ$ in terms of the lengths $b,c$ and the angle $\theta$. Show that, when $b/c$ is small, $OQ$ is given approximately by  $OQ = c + b\cos(\theta)-\frac{b^2}{2c}\sin^2(\theta)$

I have sketched a little diagram that goes as follows;

[image]

$ \cos \theta = \frac{x}{b}  $ this implies that $ b\cos\theta = x$

$ \sin \theta = \frac{h}{b}  $ this implies that $ b\sin\theta = h$

now $ c^2 = h^2 + y^2 $ so $ c^2 - h^2 = y^2 $

now i am letting the length $OQ = z$.

$z = x + y  = b\cos\theta + \sqrt{c^2 - b^2(\sin\theta)^2}$

Now I know I can manipulate this more. but I feel as though i am getting further and further away. I may have made a mistake, but it is basic trig?

Comment: I would actually say that's exactly the answer you _should_ have, at least for finding $z$ as a function of $b,c,$ and $\theta$. All that's left is to find the last result, and for that it helps to know the binomial series approximation of $\sqrt{1-x}$...

Comment: but isnt that an infinite expansion as its power is not an integer power? or do i use Taylor series?

Comment: It's an infinite series, yes, but for the leading-order approximation (the one used to get their answer) you just take the first two terms of the series. In terms of Taylor series, it amounts to dropping everything past the first-order term.

Comment: Your initial expression for OQ is not consistent with the diagram - plug in $\theta=0$ and you'll have OQ=c, rather than the correct answer of b+c. The second term should be $b\cos\theta$.

Comment: That was a typo, i was about to edit. thanks for pointing it out though! also semi classical, thanks VERY much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to remember is that the linking rods are rigid and must maintain their length throughout.

Put the origin at O. The point P is instantaneously $b\cos\theta, b\sin\theta$ which automatically satisfies $|OP|=b$. If $Q=(z,0)$, one must have $|PQ|=c$. This gives you

$$
(z-b\cos\theta)^2 + (b\sin\theta)^2 = c^2 \\
z^2 - 2bz \cos\theta + b^2-c^2 = 0
$$
Solving this quadratic for $z$ you have

$$
z = b\cos\theta \pm \sqrt{c^2-b^2\sin^2\theta} \\
  = b\cos\theta \pm c\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{c^2}\sin^2\theta} 
$$
You have to take the positive root since the length is b+c at $\theta=0$.

For small $b/c$, you can expand the square root term in a Taylor series as $(1+x)^{(1/2)} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{2}$, giving you
$$
z \approx b\cos\theta + c - \frac{b^2}{2c} \sin^2\theta
$$